# Show the linear combination $\hat p* = X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3$ is not sufficient for $p$. Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be a set of three independent Bernoulli random variables with unknown parameter $p = P(X_i = 1)$. Where it is given that  $ \hat p = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ is sufficient for $p$. Show that the linear combination $\hat p* = X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3$ is not sufficient for $p$.

Attempt: We must show the conditional probability does not depend on $p$ . So $\hat p*$ is will not be sufficient.
Now,  $P( X_1 = k_1, ...,X_n   | \hat p = p_e) = \frac{P( X_1 = k_1, ...,X_n and   | \hat p = p_e)}{P(\hat p = p_e)} $

$P[(X_1, X_2, X_3) | X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3 = 3) = \frac{P( (X_1, X_2, X_3) and   X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3 = 3 )}{P(\hat  X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3 = 3)}  $

Can someone please help me? I don't know what to put for the $X_1,X_2,X_3$ Can I put $(1,1,1)$ then the probability would be $p^3$ in the numerator. Can anyone please give some feedback?
Thank you

Comment: Suppose $T=X_1+2X_2+3X_3$.

Consider the case $T=3$, which means the tuples $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$ are the only possible values assumed by $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$.

That is, $P(T=3)=P(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0)+P(X_1=0,X_2=0,X_3=1)$.

Then a routine calculation gives $$P(X_1=0,X_2=0,X_3=1\mid T=3)=1-p$$

which clearly depends on $p$. So $T$ is not sufficient for $p$.